# Are precompield headers a good way to hide code?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, g++, clang

I've been working on a project where preferably I would hide the contents of the header files. I came to the idea recently of precompiled headers. How valid of a use case are these things?

Comment: Headers generally need to be precompiled on the same system that the actual compilation happens. You still need to have the header available. What is the goal of "hiding" the header file?

Comment: Essentially I'd be hiding the contents of the header files from an end user of a framework.

Comment: The purpose of header files is to describe the interface that the user has to use. Why would you want to hide that? It is exactly the part of your program that you need to communicate with the framework user. You can put everything that isn't part of the interface in a separate source file and hand it out only in compiled form.

Comment: The interface that they're using isn't hidden. What's hidden is the part of the framework that's used internally

Comment: Sounds like you need *two* header files, one for the interface and one for the internal stuff.  Don't give out the internal one.

Comment: If your header leaks framework details, the solution is better abstractions in your header, not trickery to obfuscate it.

Comment: A [pimpl](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pimpl) might be a better approach for your goal. I believe that precompiled headers would be unworkable for this purpose. It would likely interfere with your clients using precompiled headers for their own use, be fragile, and you would have to support how many platforms with how many compilers with how many different compiler option settings? If I saw that in a library/framework, I'd just say no.

Comment: That's fair enough @AviBerger I've been using a pimpl for the entirety of the project so far. It seems to be the most optimal approach.

Comment: If you're worried about performance, but know the sizes of your implementations, you can use a pimpl class to avoid dynamic allocations http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/090c0d4c5d0ab42a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone in the future, a precompiled header is not the answer simply because its output is not platform independent. Use of the pimpl idiom [or similar concepts] should be greatly preferred.

Comment: Note that both your question and answer are specific to particular usage. For example number of C++ libraries are designed header only. Compiling a project dependent on such libraries can become noticeably quicker with precompiled headers used.